# Powershell get current DOMAIN OR COMPUTER NAME\USER and the difference between the two

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I'm making a script for registering my API as a windows service. I followed this guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-service) and filled it to the best of my ability since i'm new to PS:

```
$acl = Get-Acl "$PSScriptRoot"
$aclRuleArgs = {DOMAIN OR COMPUTER NAME\USER}, "Read,Write,ReadAndExecute", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($aclRuleArgs)
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl "$PSScriptRoot"

New-Service -Name MyAPIService -BinaryPathName $PSScriptRoot\MyAPIService.exe -Credential {DOMAIN OR COMPUTER NAME\USER} -Description "API" -DisplayName "API Service" -StartupType Automatic
```

What I would like to know is how would i get the current domain or computer name, like i get the current directory with $PSScriptRoot. The service would be running on Windows 10. 
 I also don't know whether i should use the domain or computer name\user? In what situation would i need one or the other?

**EDIT:** With @Patrick help I made it work, here is the working script:

```
$acl = Get-Acl "$PSScriptRoot"
$aclRuleArgs = "$env:COMPUTERNAME\$env:USERNAME", "Read,Write,ReadAndExecute", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($aclRuleArgs)
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl "$PSScriptRoot"

New-Service -Name MyAPIService -BinaryPathName $PSScriptRoot\MyAPIService.exe Description "API" -DisplayName "API Service" -StartupType Automatic
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look here:
[About Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-6)

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME
$env:USERNAME
$env:USERDNSDOMAIN
```

About the user:
Is it a local or a domain user? If local, use 'COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME'. Otherwiese 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'

Comment: Thanks, these work. I tried this $aclRuleArgs= $env:COMPUTERNAME + '\' + $env:USERNAME and the output is COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME. Thats how it should be, right? I cant figure it out from the documentation. @Patrick

Comment: Might this helps how to create the rule: [powershell-setting-advanced-ntfs-permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543127/powershell-setting-advanced-ntfs-permissions) / [How to Handle NTFS Folder Permissions, Security Descriptors and ACLs in PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2010/11/12/how-to-handle-ntfs-folder-permissions-security-descriptors-and-acls-in-powershell/)

Answer (score 2):

```
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
```

It should include computer or domain name - so no need to build these yourself.
This is for the currently logged in user however - just like the environmental variables you've been advised to use in other places.

Furthermore - it can't be edited by simply overwriting the environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-check-if-the-computer-is-connected-to-a-domain-using-powershell) outlines how:

1. Through `systeminfo` :

```
> systeminfo | findstr "Domain"
```

2. Through directory service .Net class method:

```
> [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetComputerDomain()
Forest                  : redruby.net
DomainControllers       : {dcvm01.redruby.net}
Children                : {}
DomainMode              : Unknown
DomainModeLevel         : 7
Parent                  :
PdcRoleOwner            : dcvm01.redruby.net
RidRoleOwner            : dcvm01.redruby.net
InfrastructureRoleOwner : dcvm01.redruby.net
Name                    : redruby.net
```