# Apply NTFS permission to a folder thru Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to create a folder thru Powershell but I only want

```
1: Standard (SYSTEM)
2: The user that created the folder
```

I read this: [How to create folder, share and apply NTFS permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333572/how-to-create-folder-share-and-apply-ntfs-permissions) but it very overwelming to something simple I want to do.

Not only is this not a duplicate but the answer provided as duplicate does not give a good explaination on on the code.

Comment: Instead of setting an ACL object through PS it's probably a lot easier to set the ntfs permissions on the folder where you want to create the folders in and let inheritence do the rest (in the same fashion how you setup the permissions for redirected folders in a domain)

Comment: Please comment further....I set up the permissions on the BASE folder. From there, what else should I do?

Comment: Top level folder : System - full control (all folders, subfolders, files). Same for "creator/Owner". Then : domain users => read permissions and create folder permisions (set to "this folder only"). If a user then creates a subfolder he will have full permissions on that folder. You can also google on "ntfs permissions redirected folder", the setup for permissions are the same